# Ruby - Iterating over Instances

Tags: ruby, class, methods, iteration

Do instances of classes get an index set to them? And if so, would it be possible to iterate over them much like arrays in order to compress down the amount of lines of code I'm using? At the moment, my program has over 100 instances of a class and I want to write a loop so the code isn't basically just an enormous list of 'Class#new's! It kind of defeats the purpose of making the class itself in the first place (not really, but you get the idea).

Comment: I don't get the idea - could you share some code to describe what you're doing, and what you'd like to have happen instead?

Comment: "but you get the idea" – Umm … no, I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ObjectSpace](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/ObjectSpace.html) to retrieve all instantiated objects of a given class:
  let say you have a class named `MyClass` and you want all the instances of that class then

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(MyClass) do |obj|
  #do what ever you want to do with that object
end
```

how ever this is a bad idea to do it. it will also load `MyClass` instances that are still in memory from earlier requests that haven't been garbage-collected.

`attr_reader` should be set to access the obj directly (class variables). It's also possible to define methods to access them.

Comment: You may run `GC.start` first to delete remained local variables (for example it not worked right for me in a spec file without GC) - write a `puts` before `ObjectSpace` to print the count of the objects.

Answer (score 1):

Aside [Qaisar Nadeem's answer using ObjectSpace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265255/2597260) you can use variables to store instances of given class. You can use class variables:

```
class B
  @@instances = []
  def initialize
    @@instances << self
  end
  def self.instances
    @@instances
  end
end

B.new
# => #<B:0x3f54408>
B.new
# => #<B:0x3efbb90>
B.instances
# => [#<B:0x3f54408>, #<B:0x3efbb90>]
```

However inherited class use the same class variable (that may or may not be what you want):

```
class C < B
end
C.new
# => #<C:0x39900a8>
B.instances
# => [#<B:0x3f54408>, #<B:0x3efbb90>, #<C:0x39900a8>]
```

You can use class' instance variable (not the same as object's instance variable!):

```
class AA
  @instances = []
  def self.push_instance instance
    @instances << instance
  end
  def initialize
    self.class.push_instance self
  end
  def self.instances
    @instances
  end
end

AA.new
# => #<AA:0x41ba0e8>
AA.instances
# => [#<AA:0x41ba0e8>]
AA.new
# => #<AA:0x29f8638>
AA.instances
# => [#<AA:0x41ba0e8>, #<AA:0x29f8638>]

class BB < AA
  @instances = []
end

AA.instances
=> [#<AA:0x41ba0e8>, #<AA:0x29f8638>]
BB.new
=> #<BB:0x3fe8e48>
BB.new
=> #<BB:0x3fa4bf8>
BB.new
=> #<BB:0x3f43e18>
BB.instances
=> [#<BB:0x3fe8e48>, #<BB:0x3fa4bf8>, #<BB:0x3f43e18>]
AA.instances
=> [#<AA:0x41ba0e8>, #<AA:0x29f8638>]
```